# Github Desktop Mac fails to clone repo from github

Tags: macos, github, github-for-mac, github-desktop

Wanted to try out the new github desktop for mac, When I attempt to clone a repo from my github account, github desktop says "copying "username/project" it copies all the files to the selected director but when it finishes says can't find "username/project" but all the files are there. Why is github desktop trying to copy my username into the repo address instead of just the project?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjk8e.png)

Comment: cloning succeeds, however github desktop cannot locate directory. Restarted github desktop and it was able to locate repo.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this might be a bug.

Cloning succeeds in pulling files, however github desktop says it "can't locate username/project".

If you restart github desktop it will then be able to locate the repo.

This is in github desktop mac v216